# Форматирование строк как в printf

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я много искал по поводу форматирования строк как в стандартной C функции printf, так и не нашел того что мне нужно

```
printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
```

У меня есть свой собственной логгер ошибок, предупреждений и обычных сообщений по ходу работы программы. Он выглядит так:

```
CLog::PrintLine(std::format("Hello, {}", name), CLog::Warning)
```

Мне не нравится постоянное использование std::format при работе с моим логгером. Могу ли я реализовать форматирование как в printf используя VA аргументы?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь sprintf, а потом просто пишите получившуюся строку, как вам удобно. Или напишите свою функцию форматирования :)

Comment: Это добавит лишнего кода, а для меня это нежелательно

Comment: "Мы делаем быстро, качественно, дешево. Но только 2 из 3". Вы не хотите написать один раз код a la `string stringf(const char * fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,fmt);
    int len = vsnprintf(nullptr,0,fmt,args);
    string s(len,' ');
    vsnprintf(s.data(),len+1,fmt,args);
    va_end(args);
    return s;
}` - пишите многократно `format`, чего ж тогда спрашивать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо постоянного вызывания `std::format` можно пробрасывать ему аргументы, уровень значимости тоже удобнее обернуть в функцию вместо постоянного вызывания `CLog::Warning`, чтобы по итогу выходило `CLog::PrintWarning("Hello, {}", name);`:

```
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template<typename... ArgsPack>
auto MyFormat(::std::format_string<ArgsPack...> fmt, ArgsPack &&... args_pack)
{
    return ::std::vformat(fmt.get(), ::std::make_format_args(args_pack...));
}

int main()
{
    assert("-=123=-" == MyFormat("-={}=-", 123));
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cformat%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccassert%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+ArgsPack%3E%0Aauto+MyFormat(::std::format_string%3CArgsPack...%3E+fmt,+ArgsPack+%26%26...+args_pack)%0A%7B%0A++++return+::std::vformat(fmt.get(),+::std::make_format_args(args_pack...))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++assert(%22-%3D123%3D-%22+%3D%3D+MyFormat(%22-%3D%7B%7D%3D-%22,+123))%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)